# How do I call a static variable of an object using a String variable's value?

Tags: java, variables, static

I have created an object class called "Sample" and would like to access a static variable respective to an input parameter in the method the object is created.

For example:

```
    // ____ FILE 1: Sample.java _______
package com.JavaProject;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sample {

    String Sample_ID = "";
    ArrayList<String> Assay_ID = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> NCBI_ref = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Call = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Well = new ArrayList<String>();

}

// ____ FILE 2: Retreiver.java_______

public class Retreiver {
    public static void indexer (String Field){

        Sample sam = new Sample(); 
        sam.Sample_ID = "SAMPLE1"; 
        System.out.println(sam.Sample_ID); // This will print SAMPLE1 to console.
        System.out.println(sam.{Field}); // I want this to print the value of the field as per the variable's name. 
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Field = "Sample_ID";
        indexer(Field);
    }
}
```

Id like Retreiver.Indexer to print out the static variable "Sample_ID" as defined in the method's input parameter "Field".

I.E. If I input String Field = "Assay_ID" then indexer would print out the sample's Assay_ID

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reflection is your friend.

Comment: You can't do it without reflection, but why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: You don't have any static variables in your example. What makes you think `Sample_ID` is static? (Now would be a very good time to learn about and start following Java naming conventions, by the way.)

Comment: I guess before you even try to implement it with reflection you should think about why you even need this? Your "static variable" Sample_ID is btw not static, its a normal field.

Comment: Are you wanting an "associative array", i.e. a value that is mapped by a particular `String` constant?  If this is so, then you want to use a `HashMap` container defined so that the keys are your `String` constants.

Comment: Java is not meant to be used that way. Please refer to some basic tutorial online to learn the basics and see how you can solve problems with the basics. If you can't, then you might need some structure or algorithm. Rarely (or even never) you'll need to 'invent' a new language feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reflection to access fields of any object.

```
public static void indexer (String field) {
    Sample sam = new Sample(); 
    sam.Sample_ID = "SAMPLE1"; 
    try {
        Field myField = Sample.class.getDeclaredField(field);
        myField.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(sam.Sample_ID); // This will print SAMPLE1 to console.
        System.out.println(myField.get(sam)); // I want this to print the value of the field as per the variable's name. 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Reflection should be the solution of last resort for just about, well, any problem.  It seems to me that his problem has a solution somewhere in the Java Collections Framework API and, if so, that would be, oh, about a billion times better than using the Reflection API.